# Can't read folder names for some directories using "ls" in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, ls, colors

I can't decipher the folder names when using `ls`. The file names are good. The problem is the green highlight (color surrounding the text) which makes it unreadable. I tried changing the text color in preferences, but that doesn't work. It only appears for some folders. For some directories, though, the folder list appears normally. Attaching both for reference. I don't know what's wrong.

Images for reference:

`ls` in some directory:

[image: ls in some directory]

`ls` in my home directory:
[image: ls in home dir]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The green background appears when the permissions of a directory allow write access for others.

One simple option is to omit coloring and use classification markers to differentiate entries:

```
ls --color=none -F
```

Alternatively, change the color for `ls`. The settings are stored in the `$LS_COLORS` variable. Use `echo $LS_COLORS` to take a look. It stores colon-separated color settings for specific cases of files or directories.

The entry of interest is `ow=34;43` which stands for "other writable directory" and the color codes of foreground (34=blue) and background (42=green).

Maybe change it to `1;97;45` for a bold white font on purple background?

To do so, add an entry to your shell-rs-file, Assuming `bash` it would be in `~/.bashrc` as:

```
export LS_COLORS="${LS_COLORS}ow=1;97;45:"
```

In case the original `LS_COLORS` does not end with a colon, use

```
 export LS_COLORS="${LS_COLORS}:ow=1;97;45:"
```

instead. I.e. ensure that the entries are separated by a colon.

Re-source it via `. ~/.bashrc` and run the `ls`-command.

Maybe just test it in a terminal beforehand by just running the `export` command and `ls`.

More details in this very nice answer on [Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/466203/431425).

Comment: Do you mean bashrc file, not bashrs. I figured the color=None, but as you mention in the latter part, folders aren't differentiated. exporting says, unparsable value for LS_COLORS.

Comment: @kramer Yes `bashrc`, a typo. Regarding the error: probably the definitions were not properly colon-separated, check the other option with prepending colon. Otherwise also ensure to use existing color codes only!